# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, actionmailer

I'm trying to set up my rails 4 app so it sends email. Does anyone know why I am getting:

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError
534-5.7.9 Application-specific password required.
```

??????

I am using devise and have just set up a separate "share" mailer to send email. I've tried going to accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha as suggested in other responses to questions like this but nothing is changing when I restart the server and try to send an email as a user.

any ideas? Cheers!

config/environments/development.rb:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  # Gmail SMTP server setup
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :domain => "mail.google.com",
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name => "myrealaddress@gmail.com",
    :password => "myrealpassword",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

  # false prevents mail from being sent in development environment
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
end
```

mailer/share:

```
class Share < ActionMailer::Base
    default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"
  default from: "myrealaddress@gmail.com"

  def profile(profile, destination)
   @profile = profile
   mail(to: destination, subject: "sent you stuff")
  end
end
```

Comment: I think your gmail has problem, maybe it was locked. Try login with that account on gmail to see what happen.

Comment: Hi! I can log in fine. I tried unlock captcha as well which shoud allow access for 10 mins either way right..still no idea why it's not happy.

Any ideas how to disable sending so I can get rid of the browser error?

Comment: try test a simple send email function to sure it works normal

Answer (score 31):

The error is because two-factor authentication is enabled for your account. All you need to do to use a gmail account with two-factor authentication enabled is generate a new app password to use with your mailer configuration.

A new app password for gmail can be generated here - https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords.

When generating a new password choose `Mail` for the `Select App` setting and `Other(Custom name)` for the `Select Device` setting.

Once you have the new password update your mailer configuration with the random string that Google generates for you and you should be set.

Comment: I'm not sure why the OP hasn't marked this response as the correct answer - this is exactly what's called for. As more users move to 2-step, this answer will only become more relevant.